# Nav makes the font bold

Tags: html, css, fonts, navigation

So i have started working on a design for later use, i don't know why but it makes the font in my navigation bold? - I have made a drop down on hover, and when it is down the bold gets its regular weight?

I found a post the suggested i use this code:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

But it kinder reverse the thing so it is not bold from the start but when i hover an menu item the font gets bold.

Any suggestions?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vVzu/)

Comment: Not able to replicate. I think you have an optical illusion caused by the change in bg color. Insofar as the the contents of the `li` is a text node (which should really be a link or a span (or some text element) it's hard to see how the node could be affected at all.

Comment: in which browser and version does this happen? is your browser window zoomed?

Comment: After a little bit of testing, it does in Safari where the font gets normal when the dropdown menu is active, in Chrome and Firefox it is just bold all the time. - This is on my MacBook Pro. On windows it is not a problem, it works in, IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari as well.

Comment: Try setting a specified font, maybe one from Google Fonts. I think the fonts are different based on useragent styling since you did not declare any. Please provide screenshots in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this css..

```
    nav > ul > li 
    {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Comment: I dont want the text to be bold?